# CSS Menu Not working with XML rotating Banner

Tags: css, menu, slider

I tested Nvidea css drop down menu on a site with XML Flash rotating banner , it works find on opera but doent work on internet explorer and google chrome, it actually goes behind.

menu from : http://www.lwis.net/free-css-drop-down-menu/

see link here: http://sonymax.co.uk

thx

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is a problem with the menu actually, I removed the banner in IE and the drop-down menu still doesn't show up. Also note, that if you change your compatibility mode from IE7 to IE8 or 9 the menu and banner are way off. You should revise your code a bit.

It works in my Chrome, not sure why it doesn't in yours, only IE has the problem as far as I tested.